# java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider

Tags: android

I want to select image and save it in database ,when select image from gallery give me exception:

[image]

the error in `onSelectFromGalleryResult` method:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Utility.MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if(userChoosenTask.equals("Take Photo"))
                        cameraIntent();
                    else if(userChoosenTask.equals("Choose from Library"))
                        galleryIntent();
                } else {
            }
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {


        try {
    ##        bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());##
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
}`
```

manifest file

Comment: add permission Read and Write External Storage  in your manifest .......

Answer (score 0):

give permission in manifest file above application tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

Below describes methodology to check, and request, permissions. However, using the support library is simpler, since your app doesn't need to check which version of Android it's running on before calling the methods.

For more info, check out this [Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Declaring permission to be checked,

```
private static final int REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
private static final String[] STORAGE_PERMISSIONS = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
};
```

Below function will check if the permission is granted,

```
private boolean hasPermissionsGranted(String[] permissions) {
    for (String permission : permissions) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Use above function to target code which require critical permission to be granted, here is the code to do that -

```
if (!hasPermissionsGranted(STORAGE_PERMISSIONS)) {
        requestPermissions();
        return;
    }
```

Now, here is the actual code which triggers permission dialog to grant the permission from user,

```
private void requestPermissions() {
    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(STORAGE_PERMISSIONS)) {
        showPermissionDialog(); // Dialog to describe user how permission is important
    } else {
        requestPermissions(STORAGE_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}
```

Now, Handle the permissions request response,

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_STORAGE_PERMISSIONS) {
        if (grantResults.length == STORAGE_PERMISSIONS.length) {
            boolean isGranted = true;
            for (int result : grantResults) {
                if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    isGranted = false; // You can tell user that critical permission denied
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (isGranted) { // perform that critical operation here... }
        } else {
            // Tell user that critical permission denied
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do that but nothing ,the problem in this line     bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());

Comment: Are you targeting v24?

Comment: Put your full stack-trace, I need to look what actual error is. Because this seems to be a permission denial by Android M and upper version.